# TFS 2012 how to create work items for dependencies

Tags: tfs

I will be using TFS 2012 and I am confused as to how to setup work items for one job where there are dependencies to the steps needed to get the job completed.  For example, if the job first needs to get feedback from the end user, then a developer needs to build the base classes.  After the base class work is completed then another developer needs to build the UI components.  After the UI is completed then the tester needs to test the work.  This job requires multiple people, including more than one developer.  Each step cannot be started until the prior step is done.  Should all of these steps be different work items or all in one work item?  If multiple work items, how do you have the work item show as ready to work on for the next person when the prior work item is completed?  If only one work item, then how do you handle the steps for multiple developers?  This is one example.  There could be the case where we have five developers all dependent upon each other before they can start their own work.

Comment: What would happen if someone started a task before a predecessor task was complete? Would that be tragic? If the task description makes it clear what the task entails, then won't people know when it's possible for them to start their task, without being told to do so? Are these developers, or marionettes?

Comment: One developer would not be able to start working on their portion because there needs to be code checked-in by the first developer.  The base classes have to be created to then use them in the UI portion of the code.  How can I setup TFS to inform the second developer that the first developer is completed with the base class coding and the second developer can now start with their portion?

Comment: Don't do it. You are over-managing. If a developer needs part of the base class to be present, let him create it! You must really not trust your developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to fit TFS into a formal waterfall process. It probably isn't going to be a good fit in terms of creating Gantt charts for you. In TFS you can use the hierarchy of user stories and tasks to accomplish half of what you want. For the other half you can create the appropriate link type between the tasks.

However, TFS isn't going to give you a Gantt chart like view for them, it isn't designed that way. If you really want to manage projects in this fashion, I'd look at integrating TFS with MS Project and/or Project Server.

As an aside, I would strongly consider just having those people talk to each other rather than relying on a tool.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times, especially the part about having actual people actually talk to each other.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your performing an agile process your on the right track. Sprints should be based on PBI deployment, not completed tasks. If you find yourself pushing a PBI across multiple sprints, you may want to break-up your PBI. It is better to do this than keep wondering if your team is getting things done, since a group of tasks are moving into a new sprint. Getting a PBI to completed at the end of a sprint should be a key goal for an agile team.

Assign all the tasks needed to complete the PBI. Tasks should be created by the team together. This will help decide how to break down the tasks. I would break down the tasks mentioned into independent tasks based on functional groupings (UI, Business Model, ect). The art of this is to not break them down too much. The team will decide this for themselves. (remember to keep agile and let the team make short-term mistakes if it will help long-term: estimation, scope, quality, ect.

Assign QA tasks with unique names for each PBI. Don't use QA for the task name, it can become difficult to prioritize on the Board view. If you have a test team, let them create there qa tasks. Agile is agile (the team is the team).

The other main key point I learned was don't move on to tasks until the PBI has been planned completely, don't move on to sprinting until the tasks have been planned completely. This will help ensure that once your are sprinting, your not making decisions for that sprint in the middle of the sprint.

I hope this gives you some pointers.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you would split the tasks up to separate work items.  However, I am still unclear as to how I would deal with configuring TFS to inform the second developer that the first developer is completed with the base class coding and the second developer can now start with their portion.